# Flex: Why doesn't mx.core.Container always use the 'contentPane'?

Tags: apache-flex

Why is it that the [mx.core.Container](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html) uses its [contentPane](http://jonathanbranam.net/flex3anatomy/class/Container/contentPane) sometimes, but doesn't at other times?

Or, in other words, how come the children of `Container` are only put into the `contentPane` if some complex logic decides that they should be put there? Why not simply always put all children in the `contentPane`?

Comment: can you post your MXML by any chance?

Comment: Which MXML? This has nothing to do with my code - this is a question about the Flex standard library…

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, addingChild() (which is probably an inherited method) in the sdk will be your answer.  It has to do with styles and since I'm not the person to talk to about styles, I'm turning this answer into a community wiki, can't say I've ever done this...

Comment: I've looked through `addingChild`, but like most places, it doesn't seem like the optionality of `contentPane` makes sense there either - like in most places, it just serves to make the function more complex.

Comment: Yeah, looks like, as my first sentence suggests, my memory didn't serve me well.... in fact I'm pretty sure I never knew this one.  This has much less (though some) to do with styles than it does how containers work.  I googled 'contentPane flex' and there isn't much of anything out there.  Going through Container's source, it looks like it is used for scrolling.  I'm laying on the couch with a beer, so I half-assed looking through the code, but that's what she's looking like -- scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Content pane is a simple display object that the container uses internally to host children but only when scrolling enabled. So this is why the children are 'sometimes' being placed inside the content pane. :)

This content pane is then being moved and this is how the container is being scrolled.

When switching 'scrollContent' ON and OFF, Flex moves the children from the container itself to the content pane and vice versa. Before the first move to the content pane it creates the pane.

What's also important is that this process is being transparent to the user, i.e. when adding/removing children, the container takes care of where to put them (to the container itself or the content pane). Also note that the layout mechanism operates on the children the same way in both cases (either with or without the content pane).

And now the answer to the question "Why not simply always put all children in the contentPane?".

Performance! We always tend to minimize the number of components in the application, so why use the content pane with each and every container while only the small number of containers has scrollContent set to true? The majority of containers in the average Flex app is just grouping its children in the horizontal or vertical fashion.